# Multiple variables in Tikz don't work as expected

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw lines of the form `(0,0) to (radius:length)` and use `\foreach` so I don't have to write everything again and again. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \radiusA/\lengthA/\radiusB/\lengthB in {50/3/100/2} {
    \draw (0,0) -- (\radiusA:\lengthA) coordinate (P) node[above]{\radiusA:\lengthA};
    \draw (0,0) -- (\radiusB:\lengthB) coordinate (Q) node[above]{\radiusB:\lengthB};
    \draw (0,0) -- ({\radiusA+\radiusB}:{\lengthA+\lengthB}) coordinate (R) node[above]{{\radiusA+\radiusB}:{\lengthA+\lengthB}};
    \draw plot[only marks,mark=*] coordinates {(P) (Q) (R)};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But the result is:

[image: Result]

But the first line should be `(50:3)`, the second, `(100:2)`, and the third `(50+100:3+2)` hence `(150:5)`. Anyone know why it doesn't work like expected?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I get a completely different result with your code. Which version of PGF/TikZ are you using?

Comment: Works fine here. I don't get the output you posted. Is your TeX installation up to date?

Comment: See http://i.stack.imgur.com/jR4gY.png. That's what I get.

Comment: I get the same as cfr

Comment: \pgfversion tells me I'm using Tikz version 3.0.0. I just updated via TeX Live Utility and compiled again, but it shows the same strange result as in my original posting.

Comment: I get the same result as cfr. Tested with TikZ3.0.0 CVS from July 18, 2014 in MikTeX.

Comment: So you have TeX Live 2015? (You didn't get a message saying you couldn't update when you ran TeX Live Utility? I assume it would relay the message from `tlmgr` in that case.)

Comment: I've got 3.0.0 on TeX Live 2015.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X 10.10.4 Yosemite, downloaded the latest MacTex-2015 Distribution and updated via TeX Live Utility without any error messages. At the moment it says that no further updates are available. TikZ 3.0.0 is installed - at least that's what \pgfversion tells me.